# defining a subprocess inside a function in python?

Tags: python, subprocess

im having a problem with the following code.

```
    def play():
        process = "......"
        h=subprocess.Popen(process)

    def stop():
        h.terminate()
```

it says that it cannot do this because h is not defined. is this because it isn't global and if so how do i make it global so that it can find it. i have tried using `global` to define the variable `h` at the start of the program but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This defines a variable named `h` in the scope of function `play`:

```
def play():
    process = "......"
    h=subprocess.Popen(process)
```

There is no variable named `h` in the scope of function `stop`, so this fails:

```
def stop():
    h.terminate()
```

Somehow, `h` has to be sent to `stop`. I see two ways.

First option, `play` returns `h` and `stop` receives i as an argument (as in [kabanus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51693078/389289))

Second option, make a class:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.process = None

    def play(self):
        assert self.process is None, "Already playing"
        self.process = subprocess.Popen("...")

    def stop(self):
        assert self.process is not None, "Not playing"
        self.process.terminate()
        self.process = None
```